# It is possible to use an HTMLHelper not only for an attribute value but instead for the name of the attribute?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, html-helper, asp.net-webpages, razor-2

I want to generate depending on what I'm passing an specific attribute with his value. This is how I want to use the helper:

```
<sometag @PossibleHelper(parameter)/>
```

After PossibleHelper do his thing, this could be the result:

```
<sometag attributeName="attributeValue"/>
```

How can I express that in the helper?

```
@helper PossibleHelper(someType){

    if(condition){
      attributeName="attributeValue"      //this is wrong
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you're in a helper it's just regular razor syntax.

```
@helper PossibleHelper(SomeType something) {
    if (condition) {
        <span attributeName="attributeValue">blah</span>
    }
}
```

You can set an attribute like this.

```
@helper PossibleHelper(int something) {
    var attrValue = string.Empty;
    if (true) {
        attrValue = "attributeValue";
    }
    @(string.Format("attribute={0}", attrValue))
}
```

Usage:

```
<sometag @PossibleHelper(parameter)/>
```

FYI, you can also make an extension method for `HtmlHelper` which may be better if the code is shared between views or there is a decent amount of logic.

```
public static class HtmlHelperExtensions
{
    public static MvcHtmlString SomeExtension(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper)
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Tyriar. I would add (after reading and testing a little) that @functions are also alternatives to do what I ask.